# HTML post form with preset variables

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'll try and explain this as best as I can. Basically, I'm using a form to receive a comment. Upon hitting submit, the action creates a link similar to this: http://localhost:8080/camagru/comment.php?comment=test&post=Post

I have a variable with the image name in it that I want to pass as well, so something like this: http://localhost:8080/camagru/comment.php?img=test.png&comment=test&post=Post

I've tried using `<form action="<?php echo commentpost.php?img=$img?>">` But everytime the submit button is pressed, it erases the img variable from POST and only puts in the new variables from the form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could put it in a hidden form field. But if it is always the same, there is no real need to send it.

Comment: It always differs. How do I create a hidden form field with preset data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add new hidden field in form tag like that

```
<form action="commentpost.php" method="post">    
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $img ?>" name="img" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="IsSubmit" />
</form>
```

Now you can able to use `$_POST['img']`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly fine now. I appreciate the code sample, it made it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The img variable is in GET.

If you want it in POST, try `<input type="hidden" name="img" value="test.png">`

Answer (score 0):

use quotes in your case:

`<form action="<?php echo "commentpost.php?img=$img"; ?>">`

the best practice is to insert hidden element into your form:

`<input name="img1" type="hidden" value="test.png" />
<input name="img2" type="hidden" value="test2.png" />`